# Apache and Django

Tags: apache-2.2, django

I have RHEL 6 running Apache and a Django application connected via WSGI.  When I run `service httpd start`, I get a segmentation fault (in my error logs) and it reports something about "Premature end of script headers".  However, when I run `/usr/sbin/httpd`, the site runs without errors and my Django project runs just fine.

What is the difference between these two?  Is it possible I accidentally have two installations of Apache on my machine (and how could I tell)?

I'm just trying to make sure this is as clean as possible, and to remove any errors I might have...

Answer (score 0):

I have determined that it has something to do with the environment variables.  When running Apache with the service command, it disables most environment variables - but doing so the other way doesn't.  It comes down to how the Django app is written and what variables are needed (globally)